# Mistake in a mathematical formula :)

Tags: c#, math, coordinates

I need to find coordinates in a window.

Here not working formula:

```
Rectangle warwnd;
GetWindowRect(wprc.MainWindowHandle, out warwnd);
Int32 yy1 = warwnd.Height - (((warwnd.Height - warwnd.Top) / 100) * 94);
Int32 xx1 = warwnd.Width - (((warwnd.Width - warwnd.Left) / 100) * 97);
```

I need to find X,Y point in a window:
6 percent of window height  and 3 percent of window width  .

[image: Example:]

Comment: What are 100, 94 and 97 values ?

Comment: What do your magic numbers represent?

Comment: percentage point position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute coordinates of the point:

```
Rectangle warwnd;
GetWindowRect(wprc.MainWindowHandle, out warwnd);
int yy1 = warwnd.Top + (int)(warwnd.Height * 0.06);
int xx1 = warwnd.Left + (int)(warwnd.Width * 0.03);
```

Relative coordinates (with respect to the top-left corner of the window)

```
Rectangle warwnd;
GetWindowRect(wprc.MainWindowHandle, out warwnd);
int yy1 = (int)(warwnd.Height * 0.06);
int xx1 = (int)(warwnd.Width * 0.03);
```

Comment: I removed the unnecessary casts since `0.06, 0.03` are `double` and `int * double` gives `double`. Note that if you have only integers you must be careful in computing the percentage, since `6/100 = 0` unless you do `6/100.0` or `6/100(double)` which give `0.06` ...